Need help fixing my prolog code in the interface of my project
Im building an interface with the objective of diagnosing someone and providing a form of treatment including the methods of treatment, with the cost and duration of it. I start by providing a list of symptoms and asking the user if they have it (insert 1) or if they don't (insert 2). Then I associate the list of symptoms with a certain disease and I provide the information on the treatment.In theory, that is. Because when I run the code in SWI-Prolog, this is what I get back:
Derived: gripe
No more factsBaseado nos sintomas fornecidos, pode ter:
gripe
No more factsTem dor muscular?
|: 

Meaning that I was able to diagnose and tell the user the disease they have but after, we should be going to treatment, and instead it's going all the way back to question 15 (perg15) for some reason.
I've posed a similar question here already, but in the meantime changed up my code and with it, new problems arised. I'm very new to prolog, if someone could explain exactly what to change in my code I would be very grateful.
This is the code I have where I set my rules:
:- dynamic (fact/1).
:- dynamic (demo/1).
  
%A simple backward chaining rule interpreter
:-  op( 800, fx, if).
:-  op( 700, xfx, then).
:-  op( 300, xfy, or).
:-  op( 200, xfy, and).

demo( Q)  :- 
   fact( Q).

demo( Q)  :-
   if Condition then Q, %A relevant rule   
   demo( Condition). %whose condition is true 

demo( Q1 and Q2)  :-
   demo( Q1),
   demo( Q2).

demo( Q1 or Q2)  :-
   demo( Q1)
   ;
   demo( Q2).

%Simple forward chaining in Prolog

demo:- new_derived_fact( P),             %A new fact
   !,
   write( 'Derived: '), write( P), nl,
   assert( fact( P)),
   demo.
demo:- write( 'No more facts').          %All facts derived

new_derived_fact( Concl)  :-
   if Cond then Concl,               %A rule
   \+ fact( Concl),                 %Rule's conclusion not yet a fact
   composed_fact( Cond).             %Condition true?

composed_fact( Cond)  :-
   fact( Cond).                      %Simple fact

composed_fact( Cond1 and Cond2)  :-
   composed_fact( Cond1),
   composed_fact( Cond2).            %Both conjuncts true

composed_fact( Cond1 or Cond2)  :-
   composed_fact( Cond1)
   ;
   composed_fact( Cond2).

%Associating symptoms with diseases

if febre and tosse and dor_de_cabeca and cansaco then gripe.
if cansaco and palidez then anemia.
if dificuldade_respiratoria and tosse then asma.
if dor_abdominal and nausea and diarreia and vomito then gastroenterite.
if dor_de_cabeca and nausea and sensibilidade_a_luz then migranea.
if febre and dor_muscular and dor_de_cabeca and erupcoes_cutaneas then dengue.
if dor_abdominal and febre and nausea and perda_de_apetite then apendicite.
if febre and tosse and dificuldade_respiratoria and dor_no_peito then pneumonia.
if febre and dor_de_cabeca and cansaco and dor_de_garganta and inchaco_nos_ganglios then mono.
if cansaco and aumento_de_peso and intolerancia_ao_frio then hipotireoidismo.
if perda_de_peso and taquicardia and nervosismo and intolerancia_ao_calor then hipertireoidismo.
if sede_excessiva and fome_frequente and urinacao_frequente and perda_de_peso then diabetes.
if dor_lombar and rigidez_muscular then lombalgia.
if erupcoes_cutaneas and coceira and vermelhidao_na_pele then urticaria.
if dor_abdominal and diarreia and perda_de_peso and presenca_de_sangue_nas_fezes then colite_ulcerativa.
if tosse and tosse_prolongada and febre and suores_noturnos and perda_de_peso then tuberculose.
if dor_de_cabeca and tontura and falta_de_ar then hipertensao.
if dificuldade_respiratoria and cansaco and inchaco_nas_pernas and tosse and tosse_seca then insuficiencia_cardiaca.

%Treatments

tratamento(nome_tratamento, [tratamentos], custo, duracao).

tratamento(gripe, [repouso, hidratacao, paracetamol], 7, 7).
tratamento(anemia, [dieta, suplemento_ferro], 15, 15).
tratamento(asma, [inalador], 40, 10).
tratamento(gastroenterite, [hidratacao, dieta], 0, 30).
tratamento(migranea, [aspirina, repouso], 10, 10).
tratamento(dengue, [hidratacao, paracetamol], 3, 15).
tratamento(apendicite, [cirurgia], 1500, 1).
tratamento(pneumonia, [antibiotico], 10, 15).
tratamento(mono, [hidratacao, repouso], 0, 10).
tratamento(hipotireoidismo, [terapia_hormonal], 90, 3).
tratamento(hipertireoidismo, [antitireoidiano], 35, 5).
tratamento(diabetes, [dieta, exercicio, insulina], 15, 5).
tratamento(lombalgia, [fisioterapia, brufen], 10, 15).
tratamento(urticaria, [antihistaminico], 20, 5).
tratamento(colite_ulcerativa, [antiinflamatorio], 15, 7).
tratamento(tuberculose, [antibiotico], 30, 30).
tratamento(hipertensao, [dieta, antihipertensivo], 5, 15).
tratamento(insuficiencia_cardiaca, [dieta, vasodilatador, diuretico], 5, 15).


And this is my interface that I'm running:
:- dynamic (fact/1). 
:- dynamic (demo/1).

%Main Function to execute consultation

consulta :-
    iniciar_consulta,
    doenca,
    tratamento.

%Iniciate consultation

iniciar_consulta :-
    retractall(fact(_)),  
    writeln('Bem-vindo ao sistema de diagnostico medico.'),
    writeln('Por favor, responda às seguintes perguntas com 1 (sim) ou 2 (nao):'), perg1.
    
    perg1 :- writeln('Tem febre?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(febre)), perg2); (S \== 1, perg2).
    perg2 :- writeln('Tem tosse?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tosse)), perg3); (S \== 1, perg3).
    perg3 :- writeln('Tem tosse seca?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tosse_seca)), perg4); (S \== 1, perg4).
    perg4 :- writeln('Tem tosse prolongada?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tosse_prolongada)), perg5); (S \== 1, perg5).
    perg5 :- writeln('Tem cansaço?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(cansaco)), perg6); (S \== 1, perg6).
    perg6 :- writeln('Tem nervosismo?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(nervosismo)), perg7); (S \== 1, perg7).
    perg7 :- writeln('Tem naúseas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(nausea)), perg8); (S \== 1, perg8).
    perg8 :- writeln('Tem diarreia?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(diarreia)), perg9); (S \== 1, perg9).
    perg9 :- writeln('Tem vómitos?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(vomito)), perg10); (S \== 1, perg10).
    perg10 :- writeln('Tem coceira?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(coceira)), perg11); (S \== 1, perg11).
    perg11 :- writeln('Tem taquicardia?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(taquicardia)), perg12); (S \== 1, perg12).
    perg12 :- writeln('Tem tonturas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(tontura)), perg13); (S \== 1, perg13).
    perg13 :- writeln('Tem dor abdominal?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_abdominal)), perg14); (S \== 1, perg14).
    perg14 :- writeln('Tem dor de cabeca?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_de_cabeca)), perg15); (S \== 1, perg15).
    perg15 :- writeln('Tem dor muscular?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_muscular)), perg16); (S \== 1, perg16).
    perg16 :- writeln('Tem dor no peito?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_no_peito)), perg17); (S \== 1, perg17).
    perg17 :- writeln('Tem dor de garganta?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dor_de_garganta)), perg18); (S \== 1, perg18).
    perg18 :- writeln('Tem dificuldade respiratória?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(dificuldade_respiratoria)), perg19); (S \== 1, perg19).
    perg19 :- writeln('Tem rigidez muscular?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(rigidez_muscular)), perg20); (S \== 1, perg20).
    perg20 :- writeln('Tem perda de apetite?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(perda_de_apetite)), perg21); (S \== 1, perg21).
    perg21 :- writeln('Tem inchaço nos gânglios?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(inchaco_nos_ganglios)), perg22); (S \== 1, perg22).
    perg22 :- writeln('Tem inchaço nas pernas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(inchaco_nas_pernas)), perg23); (S \== 1, perg23).
    perg23 :- writeln('Tem erupções cutâneas?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(erupcoes_cutaneas)), perg24); (S \== 1, perg24).
    perg24 :- writeln('Tem vermelhidão na pele?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(vermelhidao_na_pele)), perg25); (S \== 1, perg25).
    perg25 :- writeln('Tem sensibilidade à luz?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(sensibilidade_a_luz)), perg26); (S \== 1, perg26).
    perg26 :- writeln('Tem perdido peso?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(perda_de_peso)), perg27); (S \== 1, perg27).
    perg27 :- writeln('Tem ganho peso?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(aumento_de_peso)), perg28); (S \== 1, perg28).
    perg28 :- writeln('Tem intolerância ao frio?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(intolerancia_ao_frio)), perg29); (S \== 1, perg29).
    perg29 :- writeln('Tem intolerância_ao_calor?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(intolerancia_ao_calor)), perg30); (S \== 1, perg30).
    perg30 :- writeln('Tem urinado frequentemente?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(urinacao_frequente)), perg31); (S \== 1, perg31).
    perg31 :- writeln('Tem sede excessiva?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(sede_excessiva)), perg32); (S \== 1, perg32).
    perg32 :- writeln('Tem fome frequente?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(fome_frequente)), perg33); (S \== 1, perg33).
    perg33 :- writeln('Tem presenca de sangue nas fezes?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(presenca_de_sangue_nas_fezes)), perg34); (S \== 1, perg34).
    perg34 :- writeln('Tem suores noturnos?'), read(S), (S == 1, assert(fact(suores_noturnos)), perg35); (S \== 1, perg35).
    perg35 :- writeln('Tem falta de ar?'), read(S), ((S == 1, assert(fact(falta_de_ar)), doenca); (S \== 1, doenca)).

    
%Diagnosting the disease

doenca :-
    demo,
    writeln('Baseado nos sintomas fornecidos, pode ter:'),
    findall(X, fact(X), Doencas),
    last_element(Doencas, Doenca),
    writeln(Doenca),
    tratamento.

last_element(List, Last) :- last(List, Last).

%Providing treatment for the determined disease

tratamento :-
    demo, %sistema de inferência forward, para inferir a doença.
    fact(Doenca),
    tratamento(Doenca, [Tratamentos], Custo, Duracao),
    writeln('Tratamento recomendado:'),
    write('Para tratar '),
    write(Doenca),
    write(' recomendamos o seguinte tratamento: '),
    writeln([Tratamentos]),
    writeln('Este tratamento terá um custo total de: '),
    writeln(Custo),
    writeln('E uma duração (em dias) de: '),
    writeln(Duracao).


What inputs do you enter to get it to do that?

I answer 1 to febre, tosse, cansaco and dor de cabeca the symptoms for the disease gripe and 2 to every other symptom

The problem with your code is that it is very poorly structured. I suggest you restructure it as follows:
:- op(300, xfy, or).
:- op(200, xfy, and).
:- dynamic(symptom/1).
:- dynamic(disease/1).

% USER INTERFACE

init_consultation :-
   writeln('Bem-vindo ao sistema de diagnóstico médico.'),
   writeln('Por favor, responda às perguntas com s ou n.\n'),
   check_symptoms,
   identify_diseases,
   recommend_treatments.

check_symptoms :-
   retractall(symptom(_)),
   symptoms(Symptoms),
   forall(member(Symptom,Symptoms), ask_symptom(Symptom)).

ask_symptom(Symptom) :-
   format('Tem ~w? ', [Symptom]),
   read_line_to_string(user_input, Answer),
   ignore((Answer="s", assertz(symptom(Symptom)))).

identify_diseases :-
   retractall(disease(_)),
   diseases(Diseases),
   forall(member(Disease, Diseases), prove_disease(Disease) ).

recommend_treatments :-
   forall(disease(Disease), recommend_treatment(Disease)).

recommend_treatment(Disease) :-
   treatment(Disease, Treatment, Cost, Duration),
   format('\nBaseado nos sintomas, pode ter: ~w\n', [Disease]),
   format('Tratamento recomendado: ~w\n', [Treatment]),
   format('Custo total do tratamento: ~w\n', [Cost]),
   format('Duração do tratamento (em dias): ~w\n', [Duration]).

% BACKWARD CHAINING

prove_disease(D) :- disease(D), !.
prove_disease(D) :- if(C, D), ignore((prove_symptoms(C), assertz(disease(D)))).

prove_symptoms(Q) :- symptom(Q), !.
prove_symptoms(P and Q)  :- prove_symptoms(P), prove_symptoms(Q).
prove_symptoms(P or  Q)  :- prove_symptoms(P) ; prove_symptoms(Q).

% SYMPTOMS, DISEASES AND TREATMENTS

symptoms([febre, tosse, dor_de_cabeça, cansaço, palidez, dificuldade_respiratória]).
diseases([gripe, anemia, asma]).

if(febre and tosse and dor_de_cabeça and cansaço, gripe).
if(cansaço and palidez, anemia).
if(dificuldade_respiratória and tosse, asma).

treatment(gripe,  [repouso, hidratação, paracetamol],  7,  7).
treatment(anemia, [dieta, suplemento_ferro],          15, 15).
treatment(asma,   [inalador],                         40, 10).

Example:
?- init_consultation.
Bem-vindo ao sistema de diagnóstico médico.
Por favor, responda às perguntas com s ou n.

Tem febre? s
Tem tosse? s
Tem dor_de_cabeça? s
Tem cansaço? s
Tem palidez? n
Tem dificuldade_respiratória? s

Baseado nos sintomas, pode ter: gripe
Tratamento recomendado: [repouso,hidratação,paracetamol]
Custo total do tratamento: 7
Duração do tratamento (em dias): 7

Baseado nos sintomas, pode ter: asma
Tratamento recomendado: [inalador]
Custo total do tratamento: 40
Duração do tratamento (em dias): 10
true.

